# How to Compare Columns From One Document Against Another in Excel & Highlight Values

Tags: excel, highlight

I am having trouble comparing a document of data.

As a basic breakdown, I have models of laptops that we receive and I would like to compare that to models of devices we have sold. If the laptop we receive has sold, then I would like it to be highlighted in any color.

For example, if we received a Lenovo X250 laptop, I would like the formula to search through one column in our sold document and highlight the contained value in red. Any help is appreciated!

I tried using conditional formatting in Excel and highlighting duplicate values, but I am unable to gather the information I am looking for.

This is what I am expecting:

Column A would then have "X250" highlighted in RED.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| X250 | Lenovo X250 Laptop w/ Intel Core i5-Processor |
| T410 | Dell Latitude E5470 Laptop w/ Intel Core i5-Processor |

[Example of the document I am currently using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as7Hl.png)

Comment: Your sold document is an entirely different workbook then? Because conditional formatting doesn't work cross-workbooks. You'd need a helper column that checks whether it's in the sold document or use VBA.

Comment: This is actually a great point! I can transfer the data relatively easily to the other document and simplify the process. Let me know if that helps and answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: Either transfer the sold id's to the workbook you're working in and then use conditional formatting or use a helper column then that uses XLOOKUP or a similar search function and then put the conditional formatting based on the received result from that helper column.

Comment: If possible, adding a XLOOKUP column for "Sold / Unsold" is the better option. It will give you data you can use, say if you want to count how many laptops were sold vs unsold, trends from month to month, or changes in price. You can count a "Sold / Unsold" column, but you can't count colours.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting might actually work, you know?

E.g. use this formula: `=FIND(A2,TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,B$2:B$3))`

This takes the values of column "B", glues them all together, and the `Find` function checks the presence, like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer! After trying to reconfigure the document and add this formula, I am getting the #CALC! error. I added the model information from the other document in Column A and created the following formula: =FIND(A2,TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,B$2:B1420)). In order to better display my issue, I have added a photograph of the document in the original question.